# Opening json file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I know this is a simple problem but I am new to coding and could use a hand. I need to import a json file into a variable called 'test' for use in the lower half of the code.

```
import json

CRITICAL = 0
MEDIUM = 1
HIGH = 0

f = open('ECR_scan.json', )
test = json.load(f)


resource = test["resources"][0]

finding_severity_counts = test["detail"]["finding-severity-counts"]

if "CRITICAL" in finding_severity_counts:
    critical_count = finding_severity_counts["CRITICAL"]
    if critical_count > CRITICAL:
        print("Resource {} has {} critical findings".format(resource, critical_count))
        
if "MEDIUM" in finding_severity_counts:
    medium_count = finding_severity_counts["MEDIUM"]
    if medium_count > MEDIUM:
        print("Resource {} has {} medium findings".format(resource, medium_count))
        
if "HIGH" in finding_severity_counts:
    high_count = finding_severity_counts["HIGH"]
    if high_count > HIGH:
        print("Resource {} has {} high findings".format(resource, high_count))
```

I cant get this code to work without spitting out an error. I was hoping someone could help.

Here is the json file I am trying to open.

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "85fc3613-e913-7fc4-a80c-a3753e4aa9ae",
    "detail-type": "ECR Image Scan",
    "source": "aws.ecr",
    "account":
        "123456789012",
    "time": "2019-10-29T02:36:48Z",
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "resources": [
        "arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:123456789012:repository/my-repo"
    ],
    "detail": {
        "scan-status": "COMPLETE",
        "repository-name": "my-repo",
        "finding-severity-counts": {
            "CRITICAL": 10,
            "MEDIUM": 9
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the traceback error I am getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/Final ECR test.py", line 8, in <module>
    test = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 17 column 20 (char 487)
```

Comment: I see one error. You should use `json.load(f)` if you're reading from a file `loads` takes a string. But what is the error that you're seeing?

Comment: I just edited the post with the error I am getting using load instead of loads

Comment: john, this error means that you have a problem in your json file. The file itself looks ok and it loads correctly for me. It may be some invisible character at the end of your json file

Comment: That's very unusual. I've used this exact json before and it has worked in other projects just fine. I will check the file again

Comment: I copied the json from your question into a file and run python `json.load` as you did to load it. it worked. the problem must be in the file itself

Comment: So I copied the text from above and made a new file and the issue still happens. I am using Cloud9 for my IDE. I will try using another method

Answer (score 3):

`json.loads` expects a string not a file. Try using `json.load` instead

```
with open("ECR_scan.json") as f:
    test = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Can you provide the traceback error in the original post so we can see the issue you are having?

Answer (score 0):

The control character can be allowed inside a string as follows:

```
f = open('ECR_scan.json', )
test = json.load(f,strict=False)
```

You can find this in the docs for [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), or the docs for [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

If strict is false (True is the default), then control characters will be allowed inside strings. Control characters in this context are those with character codes in the 0–31 range, including **'\t' (tab)**, **'\n'**, **'\r'** and **'\0'**.